# Alinear un elemento de NavBar a la derecha

Tags: html, bootstrap

tengo un problema.
Quiero que un elemento del navbar este a la derecha pero no puedo encontrar como.

Aca dejo el codigo del nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
<div class="container">
  {% load static %}
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand pr-5" style="border-right: 1px solid #efefef;" href="{% url "inicio" %}">
      <img src="{% static 'img/logo_muni.png' %}" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top"/>
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "historia" %}">Historia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "autoridades" %}">Autoridades</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "entidades" %}">Entidades importantes</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "contacto" %}">Contacto</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-row-reverse">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "login" %}">Iniciar Sesion</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y si preguntan, se extiende de un base.html.

Comment: Hola Lucas, ¿podrías añadir lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar "navbar-text" para que se acomode a la derecha el elemento

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
      Navbar text with an inline element
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

U otro ejemplo como este

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

referencia.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/